# Finding intersection of a line and a line segment

Tags: geometry

This sounds like a duplicate but there's this problem that's been haunting me lately. I am only in 2nd-grade middle school and we don't do much in geometry (so please try to explain as simply as possible) but I have taken it a bit further by myself. Just be prepared for improper use of words and terms.

The goal is to make a computer program that uses a ray of light and gives tyou the ability to place mirrors wherever you want. The first problem arises when I want to reflect the light. What I want to find is the point of intersection between the ray and the mirror.

More specifically, I have point $A(x_1, y_1)$
and ray $(ε)$ which starts from point $A$ and moves with vector $(x_1+1,y_1+tan(φ))$. Let $λ=tan(φ)$. I found the equation of $(ε)$ to be: $$y=λx+y_1-λx_1$$

Then I have the mirror which is a line segment with points $Β(x_2,y_2)$ and $Γ(x_3,y_3)$. The equation for $ΒΓ$ is: $$y=y_2+{y_2-y_3\over x_2-x_3}(x-x_2)$$

Now my question is, using only $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $y_1$, $y_2$ and $y_3$, how can I find the point of intersection of $(ε)$ and $ΒΓ$?

I found an article that with my equations would look something like this:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}y=λx+y_1-λx_1\\y=y_2+{y_2-y_3\over x_2-x_3}(x-x_2)\end{array}\right\}$$

Where do I even begin with this? I am so lost.

I apologize for any terrible errors with the way I presented my problem but English is not the language I learn in so I tried to be as close as I could. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Fixed. Was a mistake. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two equations are of the form
$$\begin{cases}y=\lambda x+\mu&(\text{where }\mu=y_1-\lambda x_1)\\
y=\alpha x+\beta&(\text{where }\alpha=\frac{y_2-y_3}{x_2-x_3}\text{ and }\beta=y_2-\alpha x_2).\end{cases}$$
To find the (generally unique) solution $(x,y)$, just find $x$ such that the two equations are compatible, i.e. $\alpha x+\beta=\lambda x+\mu,$ i.e.
$$x=\frac{\mu-\beta}{\alpha-\lambda}$$
and plug this value into any of the two equations to deduce $y.$

But beware that for $(x,y)$ to ly on the segment $[B\Gamma]$ (and not only on the line $B\Gamma$), you must check that
$$x_2\le x\le x_3$$
(or $x_3\le x\le x_2,$ depending which of $x_2,x_3$ is the smallest). If this is not the case, the ray won't touch the mirror.